# Joining one Golang Struct into another

Tags: go

I'm a beginner to Golang coming from JavaScript land. Is there a way to join one Golang struct into another?

Example:

```
type SimpleInfo struct {
    name string,
    age int,
}

type ComplexInfo struct {
    SimpleInfo,
    address string,
    salary int,
}
```

Ideally, the intention is to make `ComplexInfo` look like this:

```
{
    name string,
    age int,
    address string,
    salary int,
}
```

Comment: The code you've posted would have given you a very clear error message if you tried to compile it. You already have a working solution that is simply broken due to unrelated typos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right road, don't use commas

```
import (
    "fmt"
)


type SimpleInfo struct {
    name string
    age int
}

type ComplexInfo struct {
    SimpleInfo
    address string
    salary int
    }

func main() {
    fa:=ComplexInfo{}   
        fa.name="frank"
        fa.salary=1000000
    fmt.Println(fa.name, fa.salary)
}
```